# Excel - Stacked Cluster X-axis label has extra space at end?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, cluster

I don't know why my chart has an extra line in my last Year of data... I added an extra space at the end for a buffer for spacing/presentation, but can't figure out why that line is still there!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

[image: Chart in Question]

Comment: Try removing the empty rows and using `Format Data Series -> Gap Width` to adjust the space between the columns

Comment: Type a space character in the cell under the last "DV" (under 2023E).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have selected the correct data source.

[image]

If you select an extra line of blank lines, this kind of problem will occur.

[image]